# Does clicking on "new circuit for this site" too often risk deanonymization?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, circuit, deanonymization

I have a (probably stupid) quirk/[OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder): When I want my traffic to a website to be particularly hard to backtrace, I click dozens of times on the `new circuit for this site` button (sometimes for >15 minutes) until I get a combination of countries which don't cooperate with each other, therefore making it harder to potentially trace back the traffic to me. Once I have a route I like, I start using the website.

However in this process I create dozens of routes from me to this site, thereby probably drawing unwanted attention to me and making it easier to deanonymize me. It also wastes Tor resources.

I would be thankful for a *technical* analysis of how valid my concerns are and an assessment of whether or not the advantage of a geopolitical advantageous circuit outweighs the drawback of the multitude of potentially denonymizing trials I need to get there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is **not** an issue, but you should elaborate using Tor Control Protocol via Stem or a similar library to build a circuit you want *a way faster*

Comment: Thanks. Sounds interesting. Can you give a bit more details please?

Comment: will do on Monday - I'm away from my main PC for a vacation